# How to initialize a constructor that expects a vector<int>& variable in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, initialization, binary-search-tree

So for a homework question, I am given the following constructor for a BST class:

```
BST::BST(vector<int>& nums)
{
    // Code
}
```

I'm having issues initializing the BST class using a vector of ints that I created. This is how it looks like in the main.cpp file:

```
vector<int>* T1;
// Fill the vector with ints
MyBST* tree1 = new MyBST();
tree1 = MyBST(T1);
```

What is the correct way of initializing the vector and then creating a BST variable with it?

Comment: You should read a book about C++ - since from what I can see, you are having difficulties with basic syntax. 1) Why are you _trying_ to use pointer to `vector`? 2) Why are you creating your class on the heap (and trying to create a memory leak, in addition to that)? Is there any reason to? Why not just `std::vector<int> T1; MyBST tree1 (T1);`?

Comment: I suspect the purpose of this constructor is to populate a BST given a reference to a vector of `int`. The pointless naked dynamic allocation of `tree1`, followed by an invalid assignment (that would be a blatant memory leak were it allowed to compile, which it won't), I surmise it is probably in your best interest to avoid throwing things at the wall to see what sticks and review your course material. Algirdas closing two code lines in his comment do exactly what you ask. if you don't understand that, you probably need a bit more study time.

Answer (score 0):

That is simply not possible.

To create a BST, you would need minimum two vectors/arrays, one storing inorder traversal, and another storing postorder/preorder traversal of the BST.

How shall you distinguish between them, considering all of them are BST.

```
1
  \
   2 
     \
       3

   2
  /  \
 1    3

       3
      / 
     2 
    /
   1
```

Comment: I see what you are saying, however, the BST implemented in this assignment just takes one traversal. That way you can create a BST class by passing a vector of ints say {1,2,3} or {2,1,3} or {3,2,1}. My confusion is in the syntax of the BST constructor. How would I pass the vector so that it is in the format of `vector<int>& nums`? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can pass the container `vector` by reference in order to modify it in the function. you just need to pass the plain `vector`, as you do in pass by value case.

Answer (score 0):

So I actually messed up the header file for MyBST. MyBST was an extension of BST, and the constructor that used vectors was part of a BST class. So after some research, I just needed to add `using BST::BST` in the MyBST header file, and that allowed me to execute the function normally. Thanks to all for the help!